# How to get the client versions of Zookeeper connected to the server?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are upgrading the ZK Server and would like to know the version clients are using to connect so we have a better overview which clients need to be upgraded.

Is there a way of doing this? I tried 'cons' but no luck.

Thx for any advice .

Answer (score 0):

Client versions are added to zookeeper log files when connecting. Considering you have set INFO level on log4j zookeeper configuration, you should observe entries like the following:

```
2020-10-13 16:38:01,275 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@98] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.2--803c7f1a12f85978cb049af5e4ef23bd8b688715, built on 09/04/2020 12:44 GMT
```

Comment: though it isn't. To elaborate on that, in our infrastructure we use 3.6.1 version. I connected using the 3.6.2 ZK client and I got that log entry